# How to use DPI systemVerilog to detect a substring match?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

How do I use SystemVerilog DPI to check if some string contains another string? For example, strstr() in C can detect "str" is contained within "string".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by DPI systemverilog? If you want to use functions similar to C functions, then I would highly suggest the svlib library by Verilab. It provides string manipulation methods using the `Str` class

http://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/

Answer (score 0):

UVM has regexp string methods built in.  It's widely supported and optimized.

You want "uvm_re_match()" to do exactly what you want.

https://dvteclipse.com/uvm-1.2_Public_API/summary-function-uvm_pkg.html#function_uvm_re_match